Battle of Hogwarts: Fred Weasley
Is the true cause of death of Fred Weasley known in Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallow? The book refers to it as a blast through the wall while Percy and Fred were duelling the Death Eaters. What I'm wondering is what exactly caused the blast. I imagine it could be a missed spell or a giant's club, but I'm not sure. Does anyone know?
